# To DRY or not to DRY?

Tags: dry

That is the question. I have a class that have some actions that can be done, and each action have own access callback, which decides whether the current user can do it or not.
Some access callbacks share the same logic and I am not sure if I should repeat this logic or better use one method as access callback for both of these actions.

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class Foo {
  function init() {
    // These two actions have different access callbacks that implement the same logic.
    $this->createAction('Do something', 'doSomething', 'canDoSomething');
    $this->createAction('Do something else', 'doSomethingElse', 'canDoSomethingElse');
    // And these actions have one access callback.
    $this->createAction('Do Bar', 'doBar', 'todayIsSaturday');
    $this->createAction('Do Baz', 'doBaz', 'todayIsSaturday');
  }

  function createAction($name, $callback, $access_callback);

  function canDoSomething() {
    return 'Saturday' == date('l');
  }

  function canDoSomethingElse() {
   return 'Saturday' == date('l');
  }

  function todayIsSaturday() {
    return 'Saturday' == date('l');
  }

}
```

The second way looks much better at first sight but it becomes too hard to choose a right name for these reused methods when logic becomes more complicated.

```
function howToNameMe() {
  return 'Saturday' == date('l') || 42 == mt_rand();
}
```

And also when we have lots of actions and some of them use same access callbacks it can lead us to mistake when someone changes access callback for one method but the change also affects another.